# "That's so like you!" or "That's typical of you" in chinese

Tags: translation, phrase

I'm having trouble formulating "That's so like you!" or "That's typical of you" in Chinese. I'm trying to write a dialogue where a friend responds to someone who lost their phone, by replying "That's typical of you!"... But is there an appropriate way to say this in Chinese? Would appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 3):

> "That's so like you!" or "That's typical of you"
>
> literal translation: "這還真像是你" , "真是典型的你"

To translate English expressions word by word might not sound natural in native Chinese's ears, because Chinese don't phrase words the same as English

The typical Chinese phrase in this context would be more detailed:

> "這還真像是你(會做的事)" - "this is so like something you would do"
>
> "真是典型的你(會做的事)" - "It is something the typical you would do"

or you can use interpretation:

> "還真是老樣子的你" - "it is the same old (typical) you"

Answer (score 1):

tang ho's answer is correct but formal.
if you are looking for translation in slang you can say '你就这样！', '你就是这样的人！'

Answer (score 0):

More Chinese way in spoken can be: 你总这样！or 你竟干这种事！

Answer (score 0):

- 这是你的特点。
- 这是你的作为。
- 这是你的人格。
- 这是你的象征。
- 这是你的为人。